# Singleton service across AppModule and library

Tags: angular, singleton, angular-library

## Context

I have an angular app containing two libraries: DashboardLib and ChartsLib. On a component of my app I have a dashboard from DashboardLib and the dashboard itself use charts from ChartsLib.
I need to define a global timer to synchronize my charts. So, I created a service `TimerService` in ChartsLib handling setInterval of my Subject to synchronize the charts.

The charts are listening to the timer service and the root app is starting the timer.

## Problem

I tried to Inject my service using `providedIn: 'root'` (even `providedIn: 'platform'`) and `forRoot()`, but I still can't have a shared service between the root app and the library itself.

I assume I did not understand how work shared services, however I don't know how to solve my problem.

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`providedIn: 'root'` is correct however you also need include an `@NgModule` declaration in your library if you aren't already and include the service as a provider. The root app then needs to include the module in its imports.

Library

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    TimerService
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
  ]
})  
export class LibModule {}
```

Root App

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    LibModule 
  ], 
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The `TimerService` should also be included as an export in your `public-api.ts` file in the library if it isn't already.

Comment: Well, it seems to work . I was sure that I tested this case though . I'm glad you solve it! Thank you!